# Spring Boot Security POST redirects to LoginPage, after Login Save Request executes

Tags: spring-boot, post, spring-security

I am facing really annoying issue and I don't know, how to progress on it. I am login into my application, navigation works well, login / logout works well. But when I want to save somewhere something, I get redirected directly to the LoginPage. In the logs only my LoginController get executed. When I login again, then my POST request executes, the data are safed. This behavior I have everywhere in the application, I think it is somehow a configuration issue on Spring Security. Any help would be very welcome.

My Spring Security Configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    final FormLoginConfigurerEnhancer enhancer;
    final AuthenticationSuccessHandler authenticationSuccessHandler;

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/webjars/**", "/css/**", "/js/**", "/images/**");
    } 

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        enhancer.addRecaptchaSupport(http.formLogin())
            .loginPage("/login")
                .successHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler)
                .and()
                .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/login", "/home", "/registration").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
        ;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth, UserDetailsService userDetailsService) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

It seems when I am saving (posting) something, in that time my user is anonymous. This is a part of logs, when I press save button:

> 2019-06-23 19:14:22.373 DEBUG 21576 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@bffd4a17: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS
>   2019-06-23 19:14:22.373 DEBUG 21576 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.s.access.vote.AffirmativeBased       : Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@47fca1e0, returned: -1
>   2019-06-23 19:14:22.373 DEBUG 21576 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Access is denied (user is anonymous); redirecting to authentication entry point

What I also found is, that the Request Session ID has become INVALID:

> 2019-06-23 19:22:29.874 DEBUG 21576 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /property/edit at position 9 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
>   2019-06-23 19:22:29.874 DEBUG 21576 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.s.w.session.SessionManagementFilter  : Requested session ID 9FBCB80752CBCFC16D704D6C3BB62E05 is invalid.

I am using Spring Boot latest 2.1.6 Version.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way, what get my problem work. But it is more a workaround without knowing, why it works now, but not before. So I write the answer here how I got it work, but any Background knowledge or better solutions still welcome.

The main problem was, that when I send a post for saving something, I got logout by Spring Security. So I played with the `.logout` in Spring Security method.

My URL for logout should be like `/login?logout`. Spring Boot somehow has a default URL as `/logout`. But I have to set the logoutUrl by hand to have my saving functions working. So now I define it like `.logoutUrl("/login?logout")`, then saving is fine. (WHEN I REMOVE IT AND SAVE SOMETHING, I GET LOGGED OUT!)

So my Spring Security is now configured as following:

```
@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    enhancer.addRecaptchaSupport(http.formLogin())
        .loginPage("/login")
            .successHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler)
            .and()
            .csrf().disable()
            .logout().logoutUrl("/login?logout")
            .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/", "/login", "/home", "/registration").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
    ;
}
```

I configured the Spring Security with `.logoutUrl("/login?logout")` ONLY, to get my application be able to save and not getting logged out. When I want to log out, I get redirected to the wrong spring default url `/logout`. So I defined now a method in my `LoginController` to redirect on the correct url.

```
@PostMapping("/logout")
public ModelAndView logout() {
    return new ModelAndView("redirect:/login?logout");
}
```

This is all super ugly and confusing, but I really dont know what is going on here. Please put Light into the Dark. Thank you so much